# Internal Server Error With apex:inputCheckboxes

Tags: apex, visualforce, gack, inputcheckboxes

I'm using an `<apex:selectCheckboxes>` element in a VF page, with the options coming from this controller method:

```
public List<SelectOption> GetTemplateOptions()
{
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

    if(templates == null)
    {
        templates = new Map<Id, Template__c>();

        for(Template__c template : [select Id, Name from Template__c where RecordType.DeveloperName = 'template'])
        {
            /* THE_BORK */
            templates.Put(template.Id, template);
        }
    }

    for(Template__c template : templates.Values()) 
    {
        /* THE_LINE */
        options.Add(new SelectOption(template.Id, template.Name));
    }

    return options;
}
```

I'm collecting the results in an initialised list of strings and it's all fine and dandy. However, if I move the line marked `THE_LINE` and put it where it says `THE_BORK`, the system is throwing an internal server error when calling an action on the page.

I've been unable to reproduce in a developer org and obviously I've found a work around, but can anyone see what's wrong here because I can't work it out (maybe I've been looking at it for too long).

Comment: I've had the same problem when I was re-populating picklist options in different methods. Had to re-initialise the list of options, otherwise I was getting the internal server error on re-rendering the page. Found a workaround too but never found out what was causing the issue...

Comment: Best guess: the JSF or JSF-like processing model expects the List<SelectOption> to be in the view state so use non-transient field syntax instead of a getter "public List<SelectOption> templateOptions { get { … }; private set; }".

Comment: From the look of the code it shouldn't matter, but the "I've been unable to reproduce in a developer org" statement makes me wonder if there are any differences in the data between the orgs?

Comment: Do you have a default value set for the checkbox? Might make a difference.

Comment: Just defaulted to blank. My test in a DE wasn't entirely identical so going to recreate it exactly sometime to see what's going on.

Comment: Salesforce provides a couple of long digit numbers that you can provide when raising a case with them, this helps them track the internal error, log a bug and eventually fix it. While this can take time to raise and process with them, it can help your future self banging your head against it and/or others.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the issue hasn't resolved itself, you could always try:

```
public SelectOption[] getTemplateOptions() {
    SelectOption[] options = new SelectOption[0];
    if(templates == null) {
        templates = new Map<Id, Template__c>(
            [SELECT Id, Name FROM Template__c WHERE RecordType.DeveloperName = 'template']
        );
    }
    for(Template__c record: templates.values()) {
        options.add(new SelectOption(record.Id, record.Name));
    }
    return options;
}
```

Often, simple changes in code structure can resolve problems. Othertimes, salesforce.com issues hot-fixes for errors like this. There's nothing wrong with the original code, outside some general optimizations as I've provided here.